# Change Radio Button Value Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a radio button value(amount) and checkbox value(amount)
when someone click the checkbox button amount has been added to radio button value amount.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="500"> Include Fare (Rs.500/-)</label>

<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="4700">Price : 4700</label>
```

If customer check the checkbox radio button value will shows as 5200

Comment: Hi Jai, welcome to Stack Overflow. I would love to help answer your question, but unfortunately it doesn't meet the quality standards for this form. Please read through SO's How to Ask a Question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your post. Then I'd be glad to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New Update**

HTML:

```
<label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="500"> Include Fare (Rs.500/-)</label>

<label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="800"> Include Other Fare (Rs.800/-)</label>

<label><input class="price-input" type="radio" name="optradio" value="4700">Price : <span class="price">4700</span></label>

<label><input class="price-input" type="radio" name="optradio" value="2000">Price 1: <span class="price">2000</span></label>
```

Javascript:

```
function increasePrice(checkbox) {
  var increase = parseInt(checkbox.value);
  debugger;
  var price_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");
  var price_span = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
  for(var i = 0; i < price_inputs.length; i++) {
    var price = price_inputs.item(i);
    var newValue =  parseInt(price.value);
    if(checkbox.checked){
      var newValue = newValue + increase;
    } else {
      var newValue = newValue - increase;
    }
    price_span.item(i).innerHTML = newValue;
    price.value = newValue;
  }
};
```

It updates the text and the value of the `radio` and goes one way and then the other, if the checkbox is unchecked it will decreased the price accordingly. Plus, it works with multiple checkboxes and radio buttons without having to change the Javascript.

You can test it out [here](https://codepen.io/lsarni/pen/bxYRvX).

Here it is all together:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="500"> Include Fare (Rs.500/-)</label>
  <label><input onclick="increasePrice(this)" type="checkbox" value="800"> Include Other Fare (Rs.800/-)</label>
  <label><input class="price-input" type="radio" name="optradio" value="4700">Price : <span class="price">4700</span></label>
  <label><input class="price-input" type="radio" name="optradio" value="2000">Price 1: <span class="price">2000</span></label>
</form>



<script>
  function increasePrice(checkbox) {
    var increase = parseInt(checkbox.value);
    var price_inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("price-input");
    var price_span = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
    for(var i = 0; i < price_inputs.length; i++) {
      var price = price_inputs.item(i);
      var newValue =  parseInt(price.value);
      if(checkbox.checked){
        var newValue = newValue + increase;
      } else {
        var newValue = newValue - increase;
      }
      price_span.item(i).innerHTML = newValue;
      price.value = newValue;
    }
  };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: checkbox having some price value, i need to add checkbox and radio field value and display near radio button field

Comment: i have 10 package field how to use this function for multiple field?????

Comment: @Jai I have updated my answer keeping those two things in mind. It works for multiple checkboxes.

Comment: its woked for one radio button, i have multiple radio button, it will change value for one radio button, i need when user check one checkbox all the radio button value will increase

Comment: @Jai I have updated to include that, but you should have explained all this from the beginning or consider using the code as a base to work on whatever is that you need

Comment: @Jai in that case it would be great if you choose it as the right answer, pressing  the tick

Answer (score 0):

I have no much information in your question for help you but I created this exemple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input  onclick="check1()"   type="radio" name="check1">check1<br>
  <input  onclick="check2()"  type="radio" name="check2">check2
</form>



<script>
function check1() {//when selected check1 do this
   //todo
}
function check2() {//when selected check2 do this
    //todo
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
function handleClick(cb) {
  var cb_val = parseInt(cb.value);
  var price = parseInt(document.getElementById("radioPrice").value);
  if (cb.checked) {
    document.getElementById("radioPrice").value = price + cb_val;
    document.getElementById("priceText").innerHTML = "Price : " + (price + cb_val);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("radioPrice").value = price - cb_val;
    document.getElementById("priceText").innerHTML = "Price : " + (price - cb_val);
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="500" onclick='handleClick(this);'> Include Fare (Rs.500/-)</label>

<label><input id="radioPrice" type="radio" name="optradio" value="4700"><span id="priceText">Price : 4700</span></label>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've used unobtrusive principles to bind even listeners to the check boxes with a common name attribute.

The `calculateFare` function then loops through the checked checked boxes and add their values to the base price. The base price is held in a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) that I have added to the radio button. This revised price is then used as the value for radio button and the display price is updated.

Using this technique you can add/remove checkboxes without having to update your script.

```js
var fareBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("[name='cbAdditional']");

//Add event listener to the check boxes
for(var i = 0; i < fareBoxes.length; i++)
{
  fareBoxes[i].addEventListener("click", calculateFare);
}

//The function attached to the event listener
function calculateFare(){
  var basePrice = parseInt(document.getElementById("price-input").dataset.baseprice, 10);
  //get selected boxes
  var checked = document.querySelectorAll("[name='cbAdditional']:checked");
  
  //Interate our checked boxes and add to the price
  for(var i = 0; i < checked.length; i++){
    basePrice += parseInt(checked[i].value,10);
  }
  
  //Set Value and display
  document.getElementById("price-input").value = basePrice;
  document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = basePrice;
  
  console.log(document.getElementById("price-input").value);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><input  type="checkbox" value="100" name="cbAdditional"> Weekend Rate (Rs.100/-)</label>
  <label><input  type="checkbox" value="200" name="cbAdditional"> Junior Fare (Rs.200/-)</label>
  <label><input  type="checkbox" value="500" name="cbAdditional"> Include Fare (Rs.500/-)</label>
  <label><input  type="checkbox" value="800" name="cbAdditional"> Include Other Fare (Rs.800/-)</label>
  <label><input id="price-input" type="radio" data-baseprice="4700" name="optradio" value="4700">Price : <span id="price">4700</span></label>
</form>
```